# Given $|f'(x)| \leq M$ prove $\{ f(\frac{1}{n}) \}_{n \geq 2}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here is my attempt at a solution. There is a portion of my solution I think may be incorrect (the portion in the grey background) and I wanted to get some insight.

**Statement:** 
 Given $f:(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f$ differentiable and for some $M>0$, $|f'(x)| \leq M$ $\forall x\in (0,1)$.  Prove $\{ f(\frac{1}{n}) \}_{n \geq 2}$ converges.

**My proof:** 
 Since $|f'(x)| \leq M $ we have $ -M \leq f'(x) \leq M$. Integrating each part of the inequality we get:

$-M\int dx \leq \int f'(x) dx  \leq M \int dx$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $|f(x)| \leq Mx+C$.

> Since $\{ f(\frac{1}{n}) \}_{n\geq 2}$ is a subsequence of $\{\frac{1}{n} \}_{n\geq 2}$ and as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow 0$, $f(\frac{1}{n})\rightarrow 0$.

Let $\epsilon = M\cdot(\frac{1}{n})+C$. Then $\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N \Rightarrow |f(\frac{1}{n})-0|<\frac{M}{n}+C=\epsilon$, hence $\{ f(\frac{1}{n}) \}_{n \geq 2}$ converges.

Comment: The statement in grey doesn't make sense: $(f(1/n))$ isn't  subsequence of $(1/n)$. In the step above, make that a definite integral, with $x$ from say $1/n$ to $1/m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't integrate $f'(x)$ and automatically assume you get back $f(x)$; the fundamental theorem of calculus doesn't hold for every possible $f'(x)$.

Instead you can use the mean value theorem to show that
$$\bigg|f\bigg({1 \over n + 1}\bigg)  - f\bigg({1 \over n}\bigg)\bigg| < M\bigg|{1 \over n + 1} - {1 \over n}\bigg|$$
This implies that the  series $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}(f\big({1 \over n + 1}\big)  - f\big({1 \over n}\big))$ converges absolutely, so it converges. This is equivalent to your limit existing.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no reason for $f(1/n)$ to go to $0$.  For example, you might have
$f(x) = 2 + x$, and then $f(1/n) \to 2$.

Hint: Show that $f(1/n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Edit. There are two other answers already posted (as I just realized after posting mine). My approach is a bit roundabout compared to them, but I will keep it. Proving that $f$ is bounded (using the Mean Value Theorem) shouldn't be a problem, indeed $|f(x)|\le |f(\frac12)|+\frac M2$.

You have proved that $f$ is bounded and I would use it in my proof. But it is not clear why $f(\frac1n)$ would be a subsequence of $\frac1n$, any why $f(\frac1n)\to0$. In fact, if say $f(x)=1$ for all x, then $f(\frac1n)\to1$.

But, as the sequence $\{f(\frac1n)\}$ is bounded, it must contain a convergent subsequence, say converging to some number $L=\lim_{k\to\infty}f(\frac1{n_k})$. We will show that $\{f(\frac1n)\}$ itself converges to $L$. Assume this was not true, then there is some $p>0$ such that infinitely many elements of $\{f(\frac1n)\}$ miss the interval $(L-p,L+p)$. These infinitely many elements would have a convergent subsequence $\{f(\frac1{n_j})\}$ with $\lim_{j\to\infty}f(\frac1{n_j})=T$ where $T\not\in(L-p,L+p)$. We may also assume that $|f(\frac1{n_k})-L|<\frac p3$ and $|f(\frac1{n_j})-T|<\frac p3$ for all $k,j$. Note that when $k\to0$ and $j\to0$ (simultaneously) the difference $\frac1{n_k}-\frac1{n_j}$ goes to $0$, but at the same time $|f(\frac1{n_k})-f(\frac1{n_j})|\ge \frac p3>0$ remains bounded away from $0$. This means the we could make the slope of the line going through the points $(\frac1{n_k},f(\frac1{n_k}))$ and $(\frac1{n_j},f(\frac1{n_j}))$ arbitrarily large (by absolute value). But this slope, by the Mean Value Theorem, would be the same as the derivative of $f$ at some point between $\frac1{n_k}$ and $\frac1{n_j}$. This is a contradiction, since you already proved that $f'$ is bounded on $(0,1)$. (Comment. For the notation to be consistent, the $n_j$ should probably be $m_j$.)